# It`s possible make Angular Routing with name of user instead of id?

Tags: javascript, angular

I know that the id must be passed in the route because in this way I can get the user object, but I want to know if it is possible this:

```
http://localhost:4200/user/1
http://localhost:4200/user/carlos -- I want this result in my URL
```

This is the routerLink That i use in users.component.html:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', user.id]">View User</a>
```

this is user.component.ts

```
 getUser(id: number) {

  this.userService.getUser(id)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
     this.user = data;
    });
}
```

this is my route

```
 { path: 'user/:id', component: UserComponent }
```

Comment: How would you handle if you have two users named "carlos"? But certainly you can. It is a question of feasibility for your app.

Comment: the router is not aware of type. In the end it's string in params and you need to convert it. So just pass `user.name` to `routerLink` and read id: string from params.

Comment: @FrankFajardo I know this, for that reason my question is whether there is any way to use the user's name once you have obtained the object when passing the id is like the friendly routes.

Comment: @CarlosMorales, are you saying the original call is for a URL with an id and then it routes to a URL with name, and passing the whole user object so there is no need to retrieve it? You could. But still you have to answer the question: how would your app handle a scenario where your user directly requests the URL `http://localhost:4200/user/carlos`, and you do not have the user id.